# Python Selenium extract chart information

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, charts

I am trying to reconstruct the chart from the website.

> https://www.castorus.com/paris-2eme-ardsmnt,d84704896

Most likely I need to scroll mouse all over the chart and get the information that appears above the data point, but I do not manage to get a routine to go from beginning to end of the chart.

Any idea I could scrape this chart please?

After a long code to get to this website using selenium (as I enter input text and submit...), thus I would like to keep using selenium.

Thank you!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post your code trail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need of selenium you can scrape the data only with `requests` as well

```py
import requests
import re
import yaml

res = requests.get('https://www.castorus.com/paris-2eme-ardsmnt,d84704896')
finds = re.findall(r'data:.(\[[\s\S]*?\])', res.text)[0]
data = yaml.load(finds.replace("'", "\""))
print(data) # your data here
```